# Delete excel sheet not in list

Tags: vba, excel

I have the follow VBA script that works well for creating new sheets and ordering them.  I am trying to delete the sheets once the item is removed from the list. How can I go about doing this?

```
Sub AddSheet()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Sheets("Master").Visible = True
    Dim bottomA As Integer
    bottomA = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim c As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each c In Sheets("01_Update_Employee_Lists").Range("E2:E" & bottomA)
        Set ws = Nothing
        On Error Resume Next
        Set ws = Worksheets(c.Value)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If ws Is Nothing Then
            Sheets("master").Select
            Sheets("master").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
            ActiveSheet.Name = c.Value
        End If
    Next c
    Sheets("Master").Visible = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

' sort worksheets in a workbook in ascending order
Dim sCount As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    sCount = Worksheets.Count
    If sCount = 1 Then Exit Sub
    For i = 1 To sCount - 1
        For j = i + 1 To sCount
            If (Worksheets(j).Name < Worksheets(i).Name) Then
                Worksheets(j).Move Before:=Worksheets(i)
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: In general, it is agreed here that [you shouldn't use greetings or salutations in your posts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276033/pointless-question-edit/276037#276037). They get in the way of us readers figuring out the actual question. I've edited them out for you this time.

Comment: How are you determining that `bottomA` is coming from `01_Update_Employee_Lists`? I wouldn't reply upon `ActiveSheet` for that and `bottomA` should be a long not an integer.

Comment: I am referencing "Sheets("01_Update_Employee_Lists").Range("E2:E" & bottomA)".

Comment: Once again, you are assigning `bottomA` a row number that is supposedly the last non-blank row in columns A. There is nothing that says that it is the column A within `01_Update_Employee_Lists` but you use it further down your code as if it was.

Comment: Two other things - a) are you really just concerned about reordering the new sheets or do you want them all reordered every time? and b) is the *Master* worksheet in your list or should it be hard-coded as skipped when deleting worksheets?

Comment: I would like master hard coded as skipped and sorted every time.

Answer (score 0):

I usually try to avoid `On Error Resume Next` whenever possible. I understand that it is an accepted programming practise but to me it just wrong to break something to show it isn't there. In any event, there are usually alternative methods.

```
Sub AddSheet()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Sheets("Master").Visible = True
    Dim wn As Long, ws As Long, rWSLST As Range

    With Sheets("01_Update_Employee_Lists")
        Set rWSLST = .Range("E2:E" & .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        For wn = 2 To .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            If CBool(Len(Trim(.Cells(wn, "E").Value))) Then
                For ws = 1 To Sheets.Count
                    If LCase(Sheets(ws).Name) = LCase(.Cells(wn, "E").Value) Then Exit For
                Next ws
                If ws > Sheets.Count Then
                    Sheets("master").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
                    Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = .Cells(wn, "E").Value
                End If
            End If
        Next wn
        For wn = 1 To (Sheets.Count - 1)
            For ws = wn + 1 To Sheets.Count
                If (Sheets(ws).Name < Sheets(wn).Name) Then
                    Sheets(ws).Move Before:=Sheets(wn)
                End If
            Next ws
        Next wn
        Sheets("Master").Move Before:=Sheets(1)
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        For ws = Sheets.Count To 1 Step -1
            If LCase(Sheets(ws).Name) <> "master" And Sheets(ws).Name <> .Name Then
                If Not CBool(Application.CountIf(rWSLST, Sheets(ws).Name)) Then
                    Sheets(ws).Delete
                End If
            End If
        Next ws
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        Set rWSLST = Nothing
    End With

    Sheets("Master").Visible = False
    'Sheets("Master").Visible = xlVeryHidden
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 End Sub
```

I've included a commented line which would set the *Master* worksheet `xlVeryHidden` where it is not even visible in the *Unhide* worksheets dialog. You only need one or the other, not both.

Comment: @Alsjka - I've modified this code to include the worksheet with the list in the ones hard-coded not to delete.

Comment: Holy expletive Batman..That is Awesome! Thank you so much..I was in process of creating an array of my sheet names to compare my range against this is much nicer..  so happy..